# php ajax success: function (msg) - get msg

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have some jquery/php code which uses ajax to call another page.

```
var pall_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({ 
           type: "POST",
           url: "do_history.php?pall_id="+pall_id,   
           success: function (msg) {
                alert (msg);

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {   
                alert('Error submitting request.'); 
            } 
        });
```

However what do I do to get the value of msg? e.g. if do_history.php is simply:

```
<?php

$text="text";
return $text;

?>
```

would 'msg' not be "text" so when I alert(msg); I would get "text" popping up on my screen.

What do I need to do to return a string value? Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo $text;` and in your `$.ajax` options add `dataType: 'text'`.

However, a better solution would be using `dataType: 'json'` and then `echo json_encode($text);` - in this case `$text` could also be an array/object/number and it would be the appropriate type in the JavaScript function
.

Answer (score 1):

You have to echo or print the variable since jquery fetches the output of your script. A simple return doesn't produce any output.

```
<?php

$text="text";
echo $text;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check jQuery mannual for function $.post,the success  param  is a function and have several params .The most common used param is msg which is the output by the request url.
 you need to know the param msg is the output of request url(do_history.php),if you use return in do_history.php,the content($text) will  not output to browser so the msg  param  will contain nothing.but if you use echo ,print etc, the content($text) will  output to browser so the msg  param  will contain the value!

Answer (score 0):

You need to output text on php side (`print 'text'; // echo 'text'`)